# Brand new Tag with 1 question not listing the question on tag page

Tags: bug

I was browsing the new tags page when I saw the tag [se-bad-field](/questions/tagged/se-bad-field). On clicking the tag it took me to the wiki page of it where it said there was already 1 question tagged with it. But as you can see in the right half of the screenshot, it wasn't displaying the question on any of the tabs.

[image]

You can see the question in the left half of the above screenshot. I only managed to open it by doing a quick <kbd>F5+Esc</kbd> combo! See screenshot:

[image]

I even turned off Ad-blocker just in case.

---

### Links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/se-bad-field
- [Findbugs Bug SE_BAD_FIELD on boolean field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089659/findbugs-bug-se-bad-field-on-boolean-field)

Comment: It's cached server side for some time. Not much we can do.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd if it was cache, how can I catch it by doing refresh-stop? I can see the question appear for a fraction of a second.

Comment: Do you have some ignored tags that apply here as well?

Comment: @Gaffi - Yes. horrible old [tag:java]. Now I can see the question. But why is there no visual indication that that has occurred?

Comment: Didn't notice you said F5 + ESC, thought you meant CTRL+F5 - well, ignored tag "issue" indeed.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - How to proceed now that I know what was causing it? Should I turn it into a feature-request that there should be some visual indication/note to say that ignored tags have this effect? Generally a user is used to seeing their ignored tags faded, but still shown, so this change in UI is slightly confusing?